C# WPF MVVM Instantiate Frame With Parameter
I have a WPF application with Window WINDOWCompanies.  Within this window, I have two Comoboxes bound to ObservableCollections in the WINDOWCompaniesVM.  The Companies combobox is populated once the Industry is selected.
There is a Stack of buttons positioned next to a Frame within the Window.  The process should go as such, Industry Selected --> Company Selected --> Then one of the buttons, "News" in this case, is pressed and a new UserControl with COMPANYNewsVM viewmodel should be shown within the Frame container of the current WINDOWCompanies.
The issue is, I don't know how to pass the selected company number (companynum) to the newly created COMPANYNewsVM.  The following classes are used for the navigation.
WINDOWCompanies.xaml :
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".05*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".95*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="#8a8ba2" Margin="5,0,0,5">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MainPageButton}"
            Content="News"
            FontSize="12"
            Command="{Binding GoToFrameVM}"
            CommandParameter="8"
        />
    </Grid>

    <Frame x:Name="PageUCContent" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,5,5" 
        Source="{Binding CurrentFrame}" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Frame.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.75"></SolidColorBrush>
        </Frame.Background>
    </Frame>
</Grid>

WINDOWCompaniesVM :
public class WINDOWCompaniesVM : _BASEVIEWMODEL
{
    private string _currentFrame;
    public string CurrentFrame
    {
        get { return _currentFrame; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _currentFrame, value, () => CurrentFrame); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Industry> _industryListALL;
    public ObservableCollection<Industry> IndustryListALL
    {
        get { return _industryListALL; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _industryListALL, value, () => IndustryListALL); }
    }

    private Int32 _selectedIndustryNum;
    public Int32 SelectedIndustryNum
    {
        get { return _selectedIndustryNum; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedIndustryNum, value, () => SelectedIndustryNum);

            if (_selectedIndustryNum == 0)
            {
                resetCompanyNamesCB();
            }
            else if (_selectedIndustryNum != 0)
            {
                resetCompanyNamesCB();
                company = new Company();
                company.fillCompaniesNamesBYIndustryPrimaryNum(SelectedIndustryNum);
                CompanyList = company.CompaniesListALL;
                SelectedCompanyNum = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Company> _companyList;
    public ObservableCollection<Company> CompanyList
    {
        get { return _companyList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _companyList, value, () => CompanyList); }
    }

    private Int32 _selectedCompanyNum;
    public Int32 SelectedCompanyNum
    {
        get { return _selectedCompanyNum; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedCompanyNum, value, () => SelectedCompanyNum); }
    }

    public NavigateFrames NavigateFramesVM { get; set; }
    public CommandGoToFrame GoToFrameVM { get; set; }

    public Industry industries { get; set; }
    public Company company { get; set; }

    public WINDOWCompaniesVM() : base()
    {
        CurrentFrame = "Views/TESTUC.xaml";

        industries = new Industry();
        industries.fillIndustriesALL();
        IndustryListALL = industries.IndustriesListALL;

        NavigateFramesVM = new NavigateFrames();
        this.GoToFrameVM = new CommandGoToFrame(this);
    }

    public void GoToFrame(string parameter)
    {
        string Index = parameter;
        int ConvertedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Index);
        NavigateFramesVM.GetFrame(ConvertedIndex);
        CurrentFrame = NavigateFramesVM.NFCurrentFrame;
    }
}

CommandGoToFrame :
public class CommandGoToFrame : ICommand
{
    public _MAINWINDOWVM MainWindowVM { get; set; }
    public WINDOWCompaniesVM WindowCompaniesVM { get; set; }

    public CommandGoToFrame(_MAINWINDOWVM mainWindowVM)
    {
        MainWindowVM = mainWindowVM;
    }

    public CommandGoToFrame(WINDOWCompaniesVM windowCompaniesVM)
    {
        WindowCompaniesVM = windowCompaniesVM;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            var s = parameter as String;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if(MainWindowVM != null)
        {
            MainWindowVM.GoToFrame(parameter as String);
        }
        else if(WindowCompaniesVM != null)
        {
            WindowCompaniesVM.GoToFrame(parameter as String);
        }
    }
}

NavigateFrames :
public class NavigateFrames : ObservableObject
{

    private string _nfCurrentFrame;
    public string NFCurrentFrame
    {
        get { return _nfCurrentFrame; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _nfCurrentFrame, value, () => NFCurrentFrame); }
    }

    private List<string> _frames;
    public List<string> Frames
    {
        get { return _frames; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _frames, value, () => Frames); }
    }

    public NavigateFrames()
    {
        Frames = new List<string>();

        Frames.Add("Views/TESTUC.xaml");            //0
        Frames.Add("Views/ADDIndustry.xaml");       //1
        Frames.Add("Views/ADDCollege.xaml");        //2
        Frames.Add("Views/ADDCompany.xaml");        //3
        Frames.Add("Views/ADDContact.xaml");        //4
        Frames.Add("Views/ADDCompanyNews.xaml");    //5
        Frames.Add("Views/ADDJob.xaml");            //6
        Frames.Add("Views/COMPANYOverview.xaml");   //7
        Frames.Add("Views/COMPANYNews.xaml");       //8

    }

    public void GetFrame(int convertedindex)
    {
        NFCurrentFrame = Frames[convertedindex];
    }
}

CompanyNewsVM :
public class COMPANYNewsVM : _BASEVIEWMODEL
{
    private ObservableCollection<CompanyNews> _companyNewsList;
    public ObservableCollection<CompanyNews> CompanyNewsList
    {
        get { return _companyNewsList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _companyNewsList, value, () => CompanyNewsList); }
    }

    private CompanyNews companynews { get; set; }

    public COMPANYNewsVM() : base()
    {
    }

    public COMPANYNewsVM(int companynum) : base()
    {
        companynews = new CompanyNews();
        companynews.fillCompanyNewsBYCompanyALL(companynum);
        CompanyNewsList = companynews.CompanyNewsALL;
    }
}

Am I wrong to think it is possible to create a new UserControl with a parameter in the Constructor using a value from the parent Window?

The Frame should not be navigated by the view model using views or URI of views as a navigation target. The view model must never instantiate or handle controls and it should not know about URIs to views.
Additionally, your ICommand implementation lacks the raising of the CanExecuteChanged event. The common pattern is to delegate the event to the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event to enable the CommandManager to raise this event for you.
Frame itself is quite heavy as its purpose is to show advanced content like HTML. It comes with a lot of overhead. For that reason, its recommended to use a simple and lightweight plain ContentControl based navigation (although Frame is an extended ContentControl) like described here: C# WPF Navigation Between Pages (Views).
However, you can mimic the MVVM navigation, which is data based and not view based as the view model has to remain view agnostic, using the ContentControl properties of the Frame.
The key is to assign a view model class to the Frame.Content e.g. via data binding and let the framework generate the views based on a DataTemplate that maps to the data model.
The following example is a refactored version of your code to make it MVVM compliant:
MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <COMPANYNewsVM />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- The DataTemplate to generate the view dynamically -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type COMPANYNewsVM}">
      <COMPANYNews />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="News"           
            Command="{Binding GoToFrameVM}"
            CommandParameter="{x:Static PageId.CompanyNews}" />

    <!-- 
      Use the Content property of the Frame. 
      Or even better, use a ContentControl instead of the Frame.
    -->
    <Frame Content="{Binding CurrentFrameData}" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>

WINDOWCompaniesVM.cs
class WINDOWCompaniesVM : INotifyPropertyChanegd
{
  public CommandGoToFrame GoToFrameVM => new CommandGoToFrame(this);

  private object _currentFrameData;
  public object CurrentFrameData
  {
    get => _currentFrame; 
    set => SetProperty(ref _currentFrame, value, () => CurrentFrame); 
  }

  private Int32 _selectedCompanyNum;
  public Int32 SelectedCompanyNum
  {
    get => _selectedCompanyNum; 
    set => SetProperty(ref _selectedCompanyNum, value, () => SelectedCompanyNum); 
  }

  public void GoToFrame(PageId pageId)
  {
    this.CurrentFrameData = NavigateFramesVM.GetFrame(pageId);
    if (this.CurrentFrameData is COMPANYNewsVM companyNewsVM)
    {
      companyNewsVM.Initialize(this.SelectedCompanyNum);
    }
  }
}

PageId.cs
enum PageId
{ 
  Default = 0,
  CompanyNews
}

CommandGoToFrame.cs
public class CommandGoToFrame : ICommand
{
  private readonly WINDOWCompaniesVM _windowCompaniesVM;

  public CommandGoToFrame(WINDOWCompaniesVM windowCompaniesVM)
  {
    _windowCompaniesVM = windowCompaniesVM;
  }

  // You must raise this event in order to allow the view to behave properly.
  // Either raise it explicitly or use the CommandManager.
  public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
  {
    add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
    remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
  }

  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    => parameter is PageId;

  public void Execute(object parameter)
    => _windowCompaniesVM.GoToFrame((PageId)parameter);
}

NavigateFrames.cs
public class NavigateFrames
{
  private object _nfCurrentFrame;
  public object NFCurrentFrame
  {
    get => _nfCurrentFrame;
    set => SetProperty(ref _nfCurrentFrame, value, () => NFCurrentFrame);
  }

  private Dictionary<PageId, Func<object>> _frames;
  public Dictionary<PageId, Func<object>> Frames
  {
    get => _frames;
    set => SetProperty(ref _frames, value, () => Frames);
  }

  public NavigateFrames()
  {
    this.Frames = new Dictionary<PageId, Func<object>>
    {
      {PageId.CompanyNews, () => new COMPANYNewsVM() }
    };
  }

  public object GetFrame(PageId pageId)
  {
    if (this.Frames.TryGetValue(pageId, out Func<object> viewModelFactory))
    {
      this.NFCurrentFrame = viewModelFactory.Invoke();
    }

    return this.NFCurrentFrame;
  }
}

COMPANYNewsVM.cs
public class COMPANYNewsVM : _BASEVIEWMODEL
{
  private ObservableCollection<CompanyNews> _companyNewsList;
  public ObservableCollection<CompanyNews> CompanyNewsList
  {
    get => _companyNewsList;
    set => SetProperty(ref _companyNewsList, value, () => CompanyNewsList);
  }

  private readonly CompanyNews _companynews { get; set; }

  public COMPANYNewsVM() : base()
  {
    companynews = new CompanyNews();
  }

  public void Initialize(int companynum)
  {
    _companynews.fillCompanyNewsBYCompanyALL(companynum);
    this.CompanyNewsList = _companynews.CompanyNewsALL;
  }
}

